# Is git add . no longer supported?

Tags: git

I always used to `git add .` to add all, but now it tells me

```
warning: You ran 'git add' with neither '-A (--all)' or '--ignore-removal',
```

Did git remove the dot notation functionality?  `git add -A` works.

Comment: Note that `git add .` never added *all* tracked files, at least not if you were in a subdirectory when running that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when you used `git add .` you were not adding all because you were ignoring the deleted things that you have done (if you have done any) so if you have deleted any file and tried to do this command , they will stay ,that's why you should probably use the `git add -A`  because most of the time that's what you probably want (Not so sure) , if you still wanna run this command , you could do `git add --ignore-removal .` Just so that you can be sure what you are doing , because you are ignoring any deletion you have done and not staging it .